# How to store a node in an array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

Isn't this a way to store a node in an array? When I try to run it I get a segmentation fault. I know that happens if you try to access memory that you do not have permission for. 
In this code am I not assigning a node in an array and printing its data?

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head = NULL;
int main(){
    struct Node* arr[10];
    head->data = 2;
    head->next = NULL;
    arr[1] = head;
    std::cout << arr[1]->data;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not dealing with `Nodes`'s here, but `Node` pointers. They are not pointing to valid memory, unless you allocate it.

Also, don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr` instead.

```
head = nullptr;
head->data = 42; // this is UB, could be a segfault
```

If you want to do that, you have to allocate it

```
head = new Node{};
head->data = 42; //ok
```

The same logic applies for `arr`

```
arr[1] = new Node{}; // now arr[1] is pointing to valid memory
```

I'm not sure why you want an array of Node pointers, though. Your `Node` struct looks like a conventional linked-list Node, and there's a `linked-list` tag, so I'm guessing you want to implement linked-lists.

In that case, you don't need an array of Node pointers at all. The entire linked-list should be connected through the `head`.

If you just want an array of Nodes, then you can do that, and not worry about memory allocation at all.

```
Node arr[10] {};
arr[1].data = 42; // ok
```

Comment: Since the OP says they want an array of nodes, then it's worth mentioning that one alternative is to actually have an array of nodes `Node arr[10];` That gets rid of the memory allocation problem. Of course the OP may not have expressed themselves correctly.

Comment: I need to make an expression tree. So, I want to store a tree in an array and use it later.